# How do I start overwriting visually selected text without c

Tags: visual-mode, replace

I would like to start overwriting immediately visually selected text without any additional keystrokes such as `c`. I am looking something similar to normal text editor where you can straightaway replace selected text by typing in new text. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: My main concern is the extra keystroke of `c` to start overwriting. Any tips/suggestions that can remove this extra keystroke in any other way are welcome :)

Comment: Can you please share the context? If by "`visually selected text`" you mean mouse selected text ([`Select-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#Select%2dmode) instead of [`Visual-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#Visual%2dmode)) you just need to remain in insert mode to achieve that. In this case [`evim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#evim%2dkeys) might be helpful.

Comment: You can start Select-mode by pressing `gh`, `gH` or `g<Ctrl-H>`, which will behave like visual mode in normal gui editors (e.g. typing will overwrite the visually selected text)

Comment: @mMontu, thank you for your suggestions. I'm looking for visual mode only not select mode. I am fine with select mode if it has the same power of expanding the selection as in visual mode. But I guess select mode is very limited in that sense. I'm curious what experienced vim users do in this case. Do they always type `s` or `c` to replace the visually selected text or do they define some mappings/commands/etc. to jump that step?

Comment: @Christian Brabandt, thank you for your suggestions. I'm looking for visual mode only not select mode. I am fine with select mode if it has the same power of expanding the selection as in visual mode. But I guess select mode is very limited in that sense. I'm curious what experienced vim users do in this case. Do they always type s or c to replace the visually selected text or do they define some mappings/commands/etc. to jump that step?

Comment: Visual mode is a launching point for many vim operations, so yes, I typically hit `c` (it’s one keystroke) once I’ve made my selection. Mappings and commands wouldnt make sense as they add complexity. And it would be difficult (not to mention counter-intuitive) to skip that step because you have to delineate « visually select text » and « change selected text ». One stroke is about as efficient as it gets.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you Ben for the clarification. I appreciate it. I personally felt a bit tired pressing that `c` or `s` to replace every selection. But seems like I have to live with it in case I want to use vim with all its functionality.

Comment: `I am fine with select mode if it has the same power of expanding the selection as in visual mode.` You have a misunderstanding here. If you want typing to immediately overwrite the text *and* you want to be able to use vim-motions to expand the text, what should happen if you type `j`? Should it overwrite the text or move the selection downwards? Think of visual mode like normal mode. It's useful for manipulating the text, but once you want to modify it you need one button to change modes (`i` from insert or `c/s` from visual)

Comment: I'm not saying you *can't* configure vim so that typing from visual will overwrite the text. That's totally an option, and you should configure your vim to behave exactly the way you want it to. I'm just saying that if you do that, you'll lose the ability to use normal mode motions from visual mode. You could get around the by using the arrow keys of course.

Comment: Thank you @DJMcMayhem for your clarification. I understand I need another keystroke to delineate the modes as also mentioned by @D.BenKnoble. In fact I also thought of similar example (typing `w`) as yours (typing `j`). I am a new user to vim, so I was thinking if there is indeed such a functionality or if I'm missing something. Now it's clear :)

Comment: `I'm curious what experienced vim users do in this case.` I see visual mode mainly as a tool to help learn the commands (like training wheels to learn to ride a bike). I believe most experienced users employ visual mode in very few/specific cases. For example: you type `vwwc` to replace the next two words, until you feel comfortable to type `c2w` and drop the visual aid. This [answer has more information about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118).

Comment: In addition to the movement regarding large blocks explained on that answer, Vim provides lots of movements to use in the current line, such as `f/F/tT`. And most of them accepts a count. So you could replace up to the start of this sentence by typing `cFS`, or c2Fm to replace up to `most` on the previous sentence. Once you can avoid smaller steps such as `j` and `l` it becomes easier to drop visual mode.

Comment: You could use visual mode as normal, expand it using the normal motions and whenever you want to replace it, use the mentioned `gH` key commands to switch to select mode. Then typing anyting will replace your selection.

Comment: @mMontu This is what exactly I am looking for as the answer!!! You see from `v2wc` to `c2w` as in your example, I am almost able to achieve what I asked in my question, avoiding the extra keystroke! Of course I asked for removal of `c` but your answer gave removal of `v`, which is absolutely fine. Thank you so much for these tips including the `c{f,F,t,T}` shortcuts. I can accept yours as the one answering my question if you want to add it. In that case, I also request you to include more such tips or links you know of (if any) (including the SO link you already shared).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, thank you Christian for the helpful suggestion. However it is one key stroke more than using `c` while I am looking to reduce keystrokes.

Comment: You could map it to a single keystroke in visual mode

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, thank you Christian for that, it will still be one extra keystroke same as using `c`.

Comment: Well, you will always have at least one keystroke to switch to overwrite mode. I mean, you could still use Select mode and navigate using `Shift` and Cursor Keys as is done in classical Windows like Editors. Or you should use Visual Mode as intended by using a model editing concept.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, Yeah I get your point Christian, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most experienced users employ visual mode in very few/specific cases.

You could use visual mode mainly as a tool to help learn the commands (like training wheels to learn to ride a bike). 
For example: you type `vwwc` to replace the next two words, until you feel comfortable to type `c2w` and drop the visual aid. This [answer ("Your problem with Vim is that you don't grok vi")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118) has more information about it.

In addition to the movement regarding large blocks explained on that answer, Vim provides lots of movements to use in the current line, such as `f/F/t/T`. And most of them accepts a count.

So you could replace up to the start of this sentence by typing `cFS`, or `c2Fm` to replace up to most on the previous sentence. Once you can avoid smaller steps such as j and l it becomes easier to drop visual mode.

Vim has a really good documentation/help system, so it is probably the best way to learn such movements (just type [`:help`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/help.txt.html#doc%2dfile%2dlist)). Here are some other good resources:

- [Coming Home to Vim](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/)
- [why use Vim](http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html)
- [Everyone Who Tried to Convince Me to use Vim was Wrong](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/29/everyone-who-tried-to-convince-me-to-use-vim-was-wrong/)
- [Answer to "Is there an interactive way to learn Vim?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579213/is-there-an-interactive-way-to-learn-vim/7579259#7579259)